# Jenkins Mac Slave Error

Tags: xcode, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins Server (Linux) with connection with Bitbucket.

For iOS projects, I needed to create a connection to a Mac OS slave, but in the slave, I can't connect to the Bitbucket repo and make the clone.

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone 
git@bitbucket.org:nameProjectGit
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone         git@bitbucket.org:nameProjectGit
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:268)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1122)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1064)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2196)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clone --progress -o origin git@bitbucket.org:mauredo/snapandsell_ios.git /Users/usertest/dev/jenkins/workspace/SnapAndSell_iOS" returned status code 128:
stdout: Cloning into '/Users/usertest/dev/jenkins/workspace/ProjectName'...

stderr: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
...
```

My project's in the master compile correctly. If I make the push from the terminal in the slave, it succeeds.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with your **GIT plugin**, which is missing an SSH component - 
namely **ssh-askpass** .

Either disable the GIT Plugin or install the missing SSH component.

Comment: I reset all my "ssh-askpass" from the Slave computer... So, when i make an new request to the "git repository", it ask me again about the permissions... Since them it start to works!!! I think this maybe some conflict between ssh key... Thanks